# How to replace LocaleRegexURLResolver from django 1.11

Tags: django, locale, django-2.0, django-1.11

I am currently upgrading Django from 1.11 to 2.0 (to 2.2 in the long run). But recently I bumped into a problem which a can't solve for quiet some time. LocaleRegexURLResolver has been removed in 2.0 without any warning and the whole code has been refactored. Sadly we were using LocaleRegexURLResolver and I am not sure how to replicate it's functionality in the current version of Django. Any ideas?

```
class SiteLocaleRegexURLResolver(LocaleRegexURLResolver):
"""
Overrides LocaleRegexURLResolver to use specified default language
by site instead of global default language
"""

def __init__(
    self, urlconf_name, site, default_kwargs=None, app_name=None, namespace=None,
    prefix_default_language=True
):
    super(LocaleRegexURLResolver, self).__init__(
        None, urlconf_name, default_kwargs, app_name, namespace,
    )
    self.prefix_default_language = prefix_default_language
    self.default_language = site.language_code

@property
def regex(self):
    language_code = get_language() or self.default_language

    if language_code not in self._regex_dict:
        if language_code == self.default_language and not self.prefix_default_language:
            regex_string = ''
        else:
            regex_string = '^%s/' % language_code
        self._regex_dict[language_code] = re.compile(regex_string, re.UNICODE)
    return self._regex_dict[language_code]
```

Basically it changes the default language. In UK, site /docs/ would be in english and /fr/docs/ in french. In FR on the other hand, /docs/ would be in french and /uk/docs/ in english

Comment: I think you'd now need to override `LocalePrefixPattern` (inside **django.urls.resolvers**). Just not sure how you tell Django to use your subclass (how did you do that with `SiteLocaleRegexURLResolver`?)

Comment: In this particular project, we also have a function `site_i18n_patterns` which overrides `i18n_patterns` from `django.conf.urls.i18n` and acts as a wrapper for `SiteLocaleRegexURLResolver`. And then when we want to use the specific functionality we do something like `urlpatterns += site_i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^docs/', include('apps.docs.urls')), prefix_default_language=False, site=PL
)` in urls.py

Comment: @PetrKučera Did you run into any solution to this?